# how to use front-end filter system in django template

Tags: django

Here in the menu section there are several food category .How can i show foods only belonging to the specific category and there is a front-end filter system in template I want to keep my design like this.How can i use front end filter system in django ?

views.py

```
def homepage(request):
    featured_dishes = Food.objects.filter(featured=True)
    menu_categories = MenuCategory.objects.filter(active=True)
    foods = Food.objects.filter(active=True)
    return render(request,'cafe/base.html',{'menu_categories':menu_categories,'featured_dishes':featured_dishes,'foods':foods})
```

base.html I have a single homepage.

```
<section class="menu-main common-padding" id="menu">
    <div class="container"> <!-- Container .// -->
{% for section in menu_sections %}
        {% if forloop.last %}
        <div class="section-heading-wrap">
            <p class="sub-heading" data-aos="fade-left" data-aos-duration="1000">{{section.section_title}}</p>
            <h3 class="main-heading u-margin-bottom-small" data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-duration="1000">{{section.title_info}}</h3>
            <p class="section-subtitle text-center normal-content" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="1000">{{section.section_description}}</p>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}

    </div> <!-- Container .// -->
<!-- this 'All' have all the active foods but when i move to other categories then how can i show foods to this category only without loading any page within this same section.what i have to do here // -->
    <div class="iso-menu">
        <ul> <li class="active" data-filter="*">All</li>
            {% for category in menu_categories %}
            <li data-filter=".{{??}}">{{category.title}}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="iso-item" data-aos="zoom-in-up" data-aos-duration="1000">
{% for food in foods %}
        {% if food.featured %}
         <div class="item dessert dinner"> <!-- Iso-Item .// --> <!-- Alternate .// -->
            <div class="menu-card-main">
                <div class="menu-card-image recommend">
                    <a href="/media/{{food.image}}" data-lightbox="menu4" data-title="Smoked Paprika Hum"><img src="/media/{{food.image}}" alt="Dish4"></a>
                </div>
                <div class="manu-card-content main-box">
                    <p class="dish-price text-center u-margin-bottom-mini">{{food.price}}</p>
                    <h4 class="dish-name text-center u-margin-bottom-small">{{food.name}}</h4>
                    <p class="dish-detail text-center">{{food.detail}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% else %}
        <div class="item dinner lunch"> <!-- Iso-Item .// -->
            <div class="menu-card-main">
                <div class="manu-card-content main-box">
                    <p class="dish-price text-center u-margin-bottom-mini">{{food.price}}</p>
                    <h4 class="dish-name text-center u-margin-bottom-small">{{food.name}}</h4>
                    <p class="dish-detail text-center">{{food.detail}}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="menu-card-image">
                    <a href="/media/{{food.image}}" data-lightbox="menu1" data-title="Grilled American Fillet"><img src="/media/{{food.image}}" alt="Dish1"></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        {% endif %}
     {% endfor %}   <!-- Iso-Item .// -->



    </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement a javascript solution.
One option is using [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX) or an http client like [Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios).

This js code should do request to your `views.py` and your `views.py` should return a response with the expected data.

Comment: This implementation required a minimal knowledge of js. You can follow [this tutorial](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/01/29/how-to-implement-dependent-or-chained-dropdown-list-with-django.html) to get familiar with this.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, i implemented django filter. I followed this article. It is very helpful for implementing simple django filter.

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/11/28/how-to-filter-querysets-dynamically.html